# how to use spesific column from postgresql and use that in if condition?

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

loginpage.php

```
            $token          = $data["token"];

            //genereted token on web
            $genereted_token    = get_random_string($user, 50);


            $_SESSION['login_success']=$login_success;

            //add sesion token
            $_SESSION['token']=$genereted_token;
            //update query token to database
            $query="update users set token='$genereted_token'"."where 
             id='$user'";
            $result=pg_exec($conn,$query);
```

mainpage.php

```
$SQL_select="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$user'limit 1";

$result=pg_exec($conn,$SQL_select);

$dt_token = pg_fetch_array($result,0);

$_SESSION['token_db'] = $dt_token["token"];

$a = $_SESSION['token_db'];
$b =$_SESSION['token'];

    if($b  == $a ){
    echo "valid token";
    }else{
    echo "invalid token ";
    }
```

I am getting *Invalid Token* every time.
NB: $a = get data from database
    $b = get data from session from login page

the problems , data from database on $a , if i'm echo he get the right result of token , and have same varible with $b but, when im use on if condition like  "if($b  == $a )" the variable not have same token data.

*sorry for my bad english

Comment: What are the values of `$a` and `$b`? Where do you define `$_SESSION['token']`?

Comment: the $_SESSION['token'] its from login page , and thas syntax from main page , so when the user login he have genereted token and save this in $_SESSION['token'] , the genereted token have update the token from database too. 
but when i call the token from database and save that in variabel a ($a), i cant use that on if  condition sir , can you help?  @The_DIctator

Answer (score 0):

lol thats problem:
before:

> $_SESSION['token_db'] = $dt_token["token"];

After:

> $_SESSION['token_db'] = trim($dt_token["token"]);